# What is the purpose of AFX_DESIGN_TIME and where it is defined?

Tags: mfc, dialog, preprocessor

I found following code in VS2015 MFC project.

```
#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME
    enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };
#endif
```

I would like to understand the purpose of this preprocessor. Google didn't give me anything sufficient. I will appreciate if you can shed some light on it.

Comment: Is this a default project? The `AFX_DESIGN_TIME` symbol suggests, that the code is conditionally enabled, when in the resource editor. That's odd, though, since `enum { IDD = .... };` is used by the dialog's base class to construct the dialog from a dialog template resource at runtime as well.

Comment: @IInspectable _"since enum { IDD = .... }; is used by the dialog's base class"_: not anymore, at least not with VS2017 and freashly created MFC projects. See my answer below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Apparently it is used by the class wizard to map the dialog ID (`IDD_DIALOG1` in your case) to the dialog class (derived from CDialoxEx).

If you remove the whole `#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME / #endif` section, the program will still compile fine, but the class wizard won't work properly anymore.

In older versions of Visual Studio, the constructor of a dialog class looked like this:

```
CSomeDlg::CSomeDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(CSomeDlg::IDD, pParent)
```

So the `CSomeDlg::IDD` symbol was actually used during the compilation and there was no `#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME`.

In recent versions of Visual Studio (at least with VS2017) the constructor of a dialog class looks like this:

```
CSomeDlg::CSomeDlg(CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(IDD_DIALOG1, pParent)
```

So the `CSomeDlg::IDD` is no more useful during compilation and therefore Microsoft decided to compile it conditionally. But this is not strictly necessary, you could remove the `#ifdef AFX_DESIGN_TIME` and the corresponding `#endif` altogether, the code would still compile and the class wizard would still work correctly.

BTW, try to replace `enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG1 };` by `enum { IDD = IDD_DIALOG123 };` and invoke the class wizard, you will get this error message:

[image]

Comment: Makes sense. Apparently, the Class Wizard is still built around a very stripped down compiler, that can identify the `enum` with a constant symbol `IDD`, rather than trying to parse through (custom) constructor calls. Quite unfortunate, that the Class Wizard can now disagree with the code that's compiled into the executable image. That's going to cause a surprise or two.